# How to automatically save DPR file when adding a new file to a project

Tags: delphi

Here's my problem. I'll add a file to a project, build, test. If everything looks good then I'll commit it(tortoise git). The problem is the DPR file never saved. The previous DPR file gets committed. I try to remember to close the project or go to the DPR file to save it, but I always forget. Is there an option in delphi to automatically save the DPR file after adding files to a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the IDE [Tools> Options> Environment Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Environment_Options), check the `Editor Files` in the `Autosave options` frame.

That will autosave all modified project files when you compile/build/run or exit.

---

Tested with my Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo IDE, by adding a unit and recompile. Should work in all Delphi versions<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Before Delphi 2010, the autosave was performed only when the code was about to be executed, or upon exit.*

Comment: Note that this option has been there since Delphi 1 but it behaved differently. While in recent versions (IIRC it started in one of the XEx-versions but I don't remember which) the files are saved on every compile (and also refactoring), in early versions they were only saved when running (with or without debugger). That was a feature that goes back even to Turbo Pascal times. For older versions, see https://blog.dummzeuch.de/2014/09/06/autosave-wizard-for-delphi-6-to-xe7/ (which currently seems to be down unfortunately).

Comment: The site is back up.

Comment: The change I mentioned above was in Delphi 2010.

Comment: @dummzeuch, Thanks, added to the answer.